# How to call instance java method in dataweave mule 4

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I have an instance method in java class `(MyUtils.getDesc(String))`
and I have to call this method from a dataweave   script .

I wrote the code below, but it is not working:

```
var obj = MyUtils::new()

test:obj.getDesc('testme').
```

Can someone help me? What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You should instantiate your object through the Java Module and its [new](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/java/java-create-instance) operation. Then you'll be able to invoke your method through DataWeave using the Java Module [invoke](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/java/java-invoke-method#invoke-methods-with-dataweave) function (supposing your instance was stored in a Mule variable named 'myUtils'):

```
Java::invoke('your.package.MyUtils', 'getDesc(String)', vars.myUtils, {arg0: 'testme'})
```

If you were dealing with a static method instead you could invoke it directly with DataWeave like this:

```
java!your::package::MyUtils::getDesc('testme')
```